# Fetch error on systemjs

Tags: typescript, systemjs, typescript2.0

I am trying to run a simple Hello World script using modules and system js but I am getting  the following error message on the console, while I only get the `Hello World from html!` message from the bare html file:

```
Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found
  Instantiating http://localhost:3000/module
  Loading http://localhost:3000/main.js
  Loading main.js
```

My index.html is:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="./system.js"></script>
        <script>
            SystemJS.import('main.js')
        </script>
        <p>Hello World from html!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my `main.ts` is:

```
import print_log from './module';

print_log();

let p: Element = document.createElement('p');
p.textContent = 'Hello World!';
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

And the `module.ts` is a simple log function:

```
export default function print_log() {
    console.log('Hello World!');
}
```

I ma serving the app through an express server.